# How to process AD security groups with Just-in-time User Provisioning?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, activedirectory

I want to auto-assign permission sets based on a user's membership in various security groups in Active Directory ("AD"), during the Just-in-Time user provisioning process. I understand that this could theoretically be possible with an Apex handler. Can anyone can confirm that Salesforce can receive a list of security group memberships from AD that can be read in Apex?

Answer (score 1):

This would have to be sent in the SAML response and read in ApEx. Since SF (acting as a SAML SP) is reading the attributes in the SAML response and transforming them to a Map which is then passed to your ApEx code, the answer to your question largely depends on how your identity provider transmits these groups. As a lowest common denominator, if each group is represented as a unique attribute on the assertion, SF will pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Group Claim under "SAML-based Sign-on -> User Attributes & Claims" if you are syncing your On-Premise to Azure.

This can also be done with a claim condition using group membership. This is not ideal, but it appears to be working for us.

User type   Scoped Groups   Source      Value
Any         1 groups        Attribute   "Your Value"

Hope this helps someone.